# CodeChef Problems: Minimum Maximum

Tags: c++

I can't seem to understand why this code isn't yielding the correct answer on CodeChef. When I run it on my machine. Seems to yield the correct *cost*

Problem Link: https://www.codechef.com/problems/MNMX

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   unsigned int T, N, cost,element,del;
   std::cout<<"Enter the Test Cases";
   std::cin>>T;
   for (unsigned int i=0;i<T;i++){

        std::cout<<"Enter the size of the array";
        std::cin>>N;
        std::cout<<"Enter the values for "<<i+1<<" Test Case"<<endl;
        vector<int> first;
        std::cout<<"enter the values of the array"<<endl;
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<N;i++){
        std::cin>>element;
        first.push_back(element);
    }

   if (N>1){
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<N;i++){
        element = 0;
       element = min (first.front() , first[1]);
       del = max (first.front() , first[1]);
       first.erase(std::remove(first.begin(), first.end(), del), first.end());
        first.push_back(element);


   }
   }
   cost = first.front();
   std::cout<<"Cost: "<<cost<<endl;

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the correct cost? What is the CodeChef cost? Does [ideone](http://ideone.com/) produce the same answer? Are you sure it is the correct one?

Comment: Look at the problem again. Now look at the problem's example and final  output. Do you see **any** of the prompts you're throwing onto the console via `std::cout`? Lose all that non-mandated output and follow the output instructions *verbatim*.

Comment: I hate code chef or alike postings here. They never turned out to add some value to the StackOverflow site.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this kind of test cases will not allow your logs to be part of this so please remove all cout statement except last, which you can modify like

```
std::cout << cost << std::endl;
```

Try this on codechef.

Or just edit last main output line as above.

Answer (score -4):

Try using different iterator variables in your for-loops, e.g. j and k for the inner loops.